# foreach() in R: return two items, rbind all first items and all second items separately

Tags: r, list, foreach, lapply, rbind

I have this problem using R and the foreach package for parallel processing.

I have one dataset per hour, for one year. Considering just one dataset, to run in parallel I use:

```
    day = foreach (h = 1:24, .combine=rbind)   %dopar%     {
    ...
    singlematrix         # return a single matrix
    }
    24matrices <- day
    # thanks to rbind, all single matrices are piled together
```

Every cycle returns a matrix, and `.combine=rbind` makes so that I obtain a bigger matrix which is the 24 single matrices piled up.

If instead of returning a matrix at every `h`, I want to achieve something like:

```
    day = foreach (h = 1:24, .combine=rbind)   %dopar%     {
    ...
    list("row"=singlerow, "matrix"=singlematrix)     # return both
    }
    24rows <- day[[1]]             # singlerows piled up
    24matrices <- day[[2]]         # singlematrices piled up
```

how can I pile all 24 singlerows together and all 24 singlematrices together, without mixing rows and matrices?

I tried inserting `.multicombine=TRUE`, returning `list( "row"=item1, "matrix"=item2)`, but the rows and the matrices get mixed together. Unfortunately I am not good with `lapply`, which maybe is the way to go here.
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I'll speculate since I don't have the actual structure of your day-to-day matrices, but perhaps this will start you in a good direction:

```
set.seed(42)
library(foreach)
day <- foreach(h = 1:24) %dopar% {
    ## ...
    mtx1 <- matrix(sample(6), nr=2)
    mtx2 <- matrix(sample(8), nr=2)
    list(mtx1, mtx2)
}

length(day)
## [1] 24
str(day[[1]])
## List of 2
##  $ : int [1:2, 1:3] 6 5 2 3 4 1
##  $ : int [1:2, 1:4] 6 1 4 8 2 3 5 7

ret1 <- do.call('rbind', lapply(day, `[[` , 1))
ret2 <- do.call('rbind', lapply(day, `[[` , 2))

str(ret1)
##  int [1:48, 1:3] 6 5 3 5 3 5 1 5 5 1 ...
str(ret2)
##  int [1:48, 1:4] 6 1 8 1 1 6 8 5 7 4 ...
```